# DING gnome-shell extension crashes repeatedly with GLib-ERROR: Creating pipes for GWakeup: too many open files

Tags: gnome-shell-extension, desktop-icons, glib

After upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, I found that my desktop icons keep popping up and disappearing in 1 second intervals rendering the desktop unusable.

Looking in the process monitor, is see that this process is repeatedly starting and closing (accompanied by `apport`):
[image]

Chasing the error down with `journalctl -f _UID=1002` , I see the following error repeatedly:

```
Dez 26 00:31:28 DesktopPC dbus-daemon[1693]: [session uid=1002 pid=1693] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.1516' (uid=1002 pid=16010 comm="gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rasters" label="unconfined")
Dez 26 00:31:28 DesktopPC dbus-daemon[1693]: [session uid=1002 pid=1693] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Dez 26 00:31:28 DesktopPC gnome-shell[1844]: DING: Detected async api for thumbnails
Dez 26 00:31:28 DesktopPC gnome-shell[1844]: DING: GNOME nautilus 42.2
Dez 26 00:31:30 DesktopPC gnome-shell[1844]: DING: (gjs:16010): GLib-ERROR **: 23:31:30.195: Creating pipes for GWakeup: Zu viele offene Dateien
Dez 26 00:31:32 DesktopPC dbus-daemon[1693]: [session uid=1002 pid=1693] Activating service name='org.gnome.ArchiveManager1' requested by ':1.1522' (uid=1002 pid=16049 comm="gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rasters" label="unconfined")
Dez 26 00:31:32 DesktopPC dbus-daemon[1693]: [session uid=1002 pid=1693] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ArchiveManager1'
Dez 26 00:31:32 DesktopPC gnome-shell[1844]: DING: Detected async api for thumbnails
Dez 26 00:31:32 DesktopPC gnome-shell[1844]: DING: GNOME nautilus 42.2
Dez 26 00:31:33 DesktopPC gnome-shell[1844]: DING: (gjs:16049): GLib-ERROR **: 23:31:33.648: Creating pipes for GWakeup: Zu viele offene Dateien
Dez 26 00:31:35 DesktopPC gnome-shell[1844]: DING: Detected async api for thumbnails
Dez 26 00:31:35 DesktopPC gnome-shell[1844]: DING: GNOME nautilus 42.2
Dez 26 00:31:36 DesktopPC gnome-shell[1844]: DING: (gjs:16086): GLib-ERROR **: 23:31:36.968: Creating pipes for GWakeup: Zu viele offene Dateien
Dez 26 00:31:38 DesktopPC nautilus[16024]: Could not delete '.meta.isrunning': Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Dez 26 00:31:39 DesktopPC dbus-daemon[1693]: [session uid=1002 pid=1693] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.1532' (uid=1002 pid=16119 comm="gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rasters" label="unconfined")
Dez 26 00:31:39 DesktopPC dbus-daemon[1693]: [session uid=1002 pid=1693] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Dez 26 00:31:39 DesktopPC gnome-shell[1844]: DING: Detected async api for thumbnails
Dez 26 00:31:39 DesktopPC gnome-shell[1844]: DING: GNOME nautilus 42.2
Dez 26 00:31:40 DesktopPC gnome-shell[1844]: DING: (gjs:16119): GLib-ERROR **: 23:31:40.446: Creating pipes for GWakeup: Zu viele offene Dateien
Dez 26 00:31:42 DesktopPC gnome-shell[1844]: DING: Detected async api for thumbnails
Dez 26 00:31:42 DesktopPC gnome-shell[1844]: DING: GNOME nautilus 42.2
Dez 26 00:31:44 DesktopPC gnome-shell[1844]: DING: (gjs:16155): GLib-ERROR **: 23:31:44.197: Creating pipes for GWakeup: Zu viele offene Dateien
Dez 26 00:31:46 DesktopPC dbus-daemon[1693]: [session uid=1002 pid=1693] Activating service name='org.gnome.ArchiveManager1' requested by ':1.1542' (uid=1002 pid=16186 comm="gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rasters" label="unconfined")
Dez 26 00:31:46 DesktopPC dbus-daemon[1693]: [session uid=1002 pid=1693] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ArchiveManager1'
Dez 26 00:31:46 DesktopPC gnome-shell[1844]: DING: Detected async api for thumbnails
Dez 26 00:31:46 DesktopPC gnome-shell[1844]: DING: GNOME nautilus 42.2
Dez 26 00:31:47 DesktopPC gnome-shell[1844]: DING: (gjs:16186): GLib-ERROR **: 23:31:47.649: Creating pipes for GWakeup: Zu viele offene Dateien
Dez 26 00:31:49 DesktopPC nautilus[16132]: Could not delete '.meta.isrunning': Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

This is stuck in a loop until I disable the extension via `gnome-extensions disable ding@rastersoft.com`.
It is worth noting that this only happens on the non-admin user accounts.

Comment: My ubuntu had slowed down to the point of death and disabling this extension brought it back. I am using a sudo account

Comment: Not sure how it got in there in the first place. Is it a part of the standard ubuntu distribution ?